# Execute a script before the branch is deleted in GitLab-CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

GitLab-CI executes the [stop-environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/index.html#stop-an-environment)  script in dynamic environments **after** the branch has been deleted. This effectively forces you to put all the teardown logic into the `.gitlab-ci.yml` instead of a script that `.gitlab-ci.yml` just calls.

Does anyone know a workaround for this? I have a shell script that removes the deployment. This script is part of the repository and can also be called locally (i.e. not onli in an CI environment). I want GitLab-CI to call this script when removing a [dynamic environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html#dynamic-environments)  but it's obviously not there anymore when the branch has been deleted. I also cannot put this script to the artifacts as it is generated before the build by a `configure` script and contains secrets. It would be great if one could execute the teardown script **before** the branch is deleted.

Here's a relevant excerpt from the `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
deploy_dynamic_staging:
    stage: deploy
    variables:
        SERVICE_NAME: foo-service-$CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG
    script:
        - ./configure
        - make deploy.staging
    environment:
        name: staging/$CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG
        on_stop: stop_dynamic_staging
    except:
        - master

stop_dynamic_staging:
    stage: deploy
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
        - make teardown # <- this fails
    when: manual
    environment:
        name: staging/$CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG
        action: stop
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not ideal, but you can curl the script using the gitlab API before running it:

```
curl  \
    -X GET https://gitlab.example. com/raw/master/script.sh\
    -H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}' > script.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

GitLab-CI executes the stop-environment script in dynamic environments after the branch has been deleted.

That includes:

> An [`on_stop` action](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#environmenton_stop), if defined, is executed.

With [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#force-stop-an-environment) (June 2022), you can skip that `on_top` action:

> ### Force stop an environment
>
> In 15.1, we added a `force` option to the stop environment API call.
>
> This allows you to delete an active environment without running the specified `on_stop` jobs in cases where running these defined actions is not desired.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#stop-an-environment) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/225794).

Comment: That does not really answer my question, my problem is that `on_stop` is executed *after* the branch is deleted, making it possible that the teardown code itself might not exist anymore. I was asking for something that is executed before the branch is deleted.

Comment: @BastianVenthur OK, then I don't know of a decent workaround, beside Anon20's answer.